# how to make changes in the child process happen in main program?

Tags: c, linux, unix, struct, fork

I'm relatively new to C and when creating one of my programs I have a struct and in the child process I change some of the attributes of that struct, but I want it to reflect on the actual struct. In the shortened version of my code my main function makes a struct called table and sets all of its attributes based on what user input then in the maketable function the child process will change the status to 1 which in this case means the program will be executed soon and call runprogram to run the table.program

```
struct task{
    int id; // id of the task
    int pid_t pid;
    int status = 0;
    JOB* program; // arguments of a program to run EX:sleep 30
}
void print_task_info(){
   // prints all attributes of task to stdout
}
void getcommand(){
   //makes a task struct and initializes it from user input
   //then calls maketable
}
void maketable(struct task table){ // is called inside getcommand()
   pid_t p;
   if((p = fork()) == 0){
      table.status = 1;
      runprogram(table); // runs the task using execvp
  }else
   getcommand(); // getcommand() basically gets an id and calls maketable
}
```

I would like to have table.status updated to 1, but the results show table.status is still 0 and not 1.

Comment: Write to a file, write to standard output, use shared memory... There’s several ways but none work without specifically implementing them and which one to use depends on what exactly it does and how much data there is etc

Comment: I recommend reading the "DESCRIPTION" section of [man 2 fork](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) and then a good follow-up with the "EXAMPLE" in [man 2 wait](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitid.2.html) is always worthwhile. Then look at the ways to communicate between parent and child with the two options in the comment above or with `pipe` and `dup2`.

Comment: [Inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)

Comment: the problem with pipe and dup2 is that I have multiple task structs and getcommand() will also use pipes for certain tasks that involve input and output files. I have googled and some say use mmap(2) would this work where changes to struct in child will happen to parent struct using mmap(2)?

Comment: `mmap` (or `shmat`) will both work. They will allow you to change the status. Be careful about 'job *PROGRAM' - you will have to place it in the shared memory, if you will need to change it.

Comment: @dash-o thank you, I just wanted to make sure how to implement it like below and do I just use mmap in the parent and the struct will be shared with child and the child of child too?
void* place = mmap(NULL, sizeof(task), .....);  
I get a initializer element is not constant error

Comment: @bobo2904 I believe anonymous mmap should work; `void *place = mmap(NULL, sizeof(struct task), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0L)` should work. You can store the address as `struct task *`

Comment: @dash-o What if I want to store multiple struct tasks in an array, how would I use mmap in this case since my program will make multiple struct tasks depending on user input?
ex: struct task table[8] // fits 8 struct tasks in array

in this case how would I implement mmap?

Comment: Assuming that you can leave with some reasonable maximum, you can change the alloc size to MAXITEMS*sizeof(struct task).

Comment: If you need something of 'industrial'  strength, consider using a library. For example: libmm. I'm not aware of standard (POSIX) library for this task.

Comment: @dash-o My current problem is 
'code' struct task* arr[8] = mmap(....)'code'
gives me an assignment to expression with array type error

Comment: Please share complete (or minimal) code to replicate. At least full line.

Comment: @dash-o I have fixed it but now I get a different error the pointer I use to mmap is at address 0x7ffff7ff4000 however in the child when I call the pointer it returns address 0x6873616220706572 and gives seg fault. If mmap is for shared memory why is the address of pointer different in parent and child?

Comment: @bobo2904 you will need to share some code - I'm not sure about your program overall flow. You want to (1) mmap before fork (2) store the pointer in a point that is available to the child. As you already figured out, the 0x6873616220706572 is `garbage`. What do you mean `when I call the pointer` ?